# Don't succeed include perl interpretator into vim

Tags: linux, perl, vim, compilation

I have Ubuntu Ubuntu 12.04.1 and I try to build vim 7.3 with perl interpreter.
I have bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
export CONF_OPT_GUI='--enable-gnome-check'
export CONF_OPT_PERL='--enable-perlinterp'
export CONF_OPT_PYTHON='--enable-pythoninterp'
export CONF_OPT_TCL='--enable-tclinterp --with-tcl=tclsh8.4'
export CONF_OPT_RUBY='--enable-rubyinterp'
export CONF_OPT_MZSCHEME='--disable-mzschemeinterp'
export CONF_OPT_CSCOPE='--enable-cscope'
export CONF_OPT_MULTIBYTE='--enable-multibyte'
export CONF_OPT_FEAT='--with-features=huge'
export CONF_OPT_COMPBY='"--with-compiledby=rodnower@gmail.com"'
```

which I run:

```
source scriptName
```

when I run 'make' following lines in the output related to perl:

```
rm -f xxd/xxd auto/osdef.h auto/pathdef.c auto/if_perl.c
        --enable-perlinterp --enable-pythoninterp  \
checking --enable-perlinterp argument... yes
checking for perl... /usr/bin/perl
```

and these lines are related to perl in src/aout/config.log:

```
  $ auto/configure --enable-gnome-check --enable-perlinterp --enable-pythoninterp --enable-tclinterp --with-tcl=tclsh8.4 --enable-rubyinterp --enable-cscope --enable-multibyte --with-features=huge --with-compiledby=rodnower@gmail.com --disable-mzschemeinterp --srcdir=. --cache-file=auto/config.cache
configure:4991: checking --enable-perlinterp argument
configure:5006: checking for perl
configure:5024: found /usr/bin/perl
configure:5036: result: /usr/bin/perl
configure:5104: gcc -o conftest -O2 -fno-strength-reduce -Wall  -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -DDEBIAN  -pipe -fstack-protector -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -I/usr/lib/perl/5.14/CORE   -I/usr/local/include  -Wl,-E   -L/usr/local/lib conftest.c  -Wl,-E  -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib  -L/usr/lib/perl/5.14/CORE -lperl -ldl -lm -lpthread -lcrypt >&5
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lperl
ac_cv_path_vi_cv_path_perl=/usr/bin/perl
vi_cv_path_perl=/usr/bin/perl
vi_cv_perllib=/usr/share/perl/5.14
vi_cv_path_perl='/usr/bin/perl'
vi_cv_perllib='/usr/share/perl/5.14'
```

After I see that perl not included into the compilation:

```
~/development/vim/vim$ src/vim --version | grep perl
+netbeans_intg +path_extra -perl +persistent_undo +postscript +printer +profile
```

This is content of /usr/lib related to perl:

```
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root           17 Sep 19 16:28 libperl.so.5.14 -> libperl.so.5.14.2
-rw-r--r--   1 root root      1584804 Aug 11 00:01 libperl.so.5.14.2
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root         4096 Aug 18 00:05 perl
drwxr-xr-x  13 root root         4096 Sep 20 00:24 perl5
```

And this is of /usr/bin:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root        545 Aug 11 00:00 cpanp-run-perl
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root       1065 Nov 15  2011 dh_perl_dbi
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root      23599 Aug 11 00:00 find2perl
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root      83452 Aug 19  2011 foomatic-perl-data
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root    1462760 Aug 11 00:01 perl
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root    1462760 Aug 11 00:01 perl5.14.2
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root      45183 Aug 11 00:00 perlbug
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root        125 Aug 11 00:01 perldoc
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root      12318 Aug 11 00:00 perlivp
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root      45183 Aug 11 00:00 perlthanks
```

These are package related to perl:

```
un  libansicolor-perl    <none>               (no description available)
un  libarchive-tar-perl  <none>               (no description available)
un  libattribute-handler <none>               (no description available)
un  libautodie-perl      <none>               (no description available)
ii  libcairo-perl        1.081-1build2        Perl interface to the Cairo graphics library
un  libcgi-pm-perl       <none>               (no description available)
ii  libclass-isa-perl    0.36-3               report the search path for a class's ISA tree
un  libcompress-raw-bzip <none>               (no description available)
un  libcompress-raw-zlib <none>               (no description available)
un  libcompress-zlib-per <none>               (no description available)
un  libcpan-meta-perl    <none>               (no description available)
un  libcpan-meta-yaml-pe <none>               (no description available)
un  libcpanplus-perl     <none>               (no description available)
ii  libcrypt-passwdmd5-p 1.3-10               interoperable MD5-based crypt() for perl
un  libdbd-anydata-perl  <none>               (no description available)
un  libdbd-csv-perl      <none>               (no description available)
ii  libdbd-mysql-perl    4.020-1build2        Perl5 database interface to the MySQL database
ii  libdbi-perl          1.616-1build2        Perl Database Interface (DBI)
un  libdevel-dprof-perl  <none>               (no description available)
un  libdigest-md5-perl   <none>               (no description available)
un  libdigest-perl       <none>               (no description available)
un  libdigest-sha-perl   <none>               (no description available)
un  libdpkg-perl         <none>               (no description available)
un  libencode-perl       <none>               (no description available)
ii  liberror-perl        0.17-1               Perl module for error/exception handling in an OO-ish wa
un  libextutils-cbuilder <none>               (no description available)
un  libextutils-command- <none>               (no description available)
un  libextutils-install- <none>               (no description available)
un  libextutils-parsexs- <none>               (no description available)
ii  libfile-basedir-perl 0.03-1fakesync1      Perl module to use the freedesktop basedir specification
ii  libfile-copy-recursi 0.38-1               Perl extension for recursively copying files and directo
ii  libfile-desktopentry 0.04-3               Perl module to handle freedesktop .desktop files
ii  libfile-mimeinfo-per 0.15-2               Perl module to determine file types
un  libfile-path-perl    <none>               (no description available)
un  libfile-spec-perl    <none>               (no description available)
un  libfile-temp-perl    <none>               (no description available)
un  libfont-freetype-per <none>               (no description available)
ii  libglib-perl         2:1.241-1            interface to the GLib and GObject libraries
ii  libgtk2-perl         2:1.223-1build3      Perl interface to the 2.x series of the Gimp Toolkit lib
un  libgtk2-perl-doc     <none>               (no description available)
ii  libhtml-template-per 2.10-1               module for using HTML Templates with Perl
un  libhttp-tiny-perl    <none>               (no description available)
un  libi18n-langtags-per <none>               (no description available)
un  libio-compress-base- <none>               (no description available)
un  libio-compress-bzip2 <none>               (no description available)
un  libio-compress-perl  <none>               (no description available)
un  libio-compress-zlib- <none>               (no description available)
un  libio-zlib-perl      <none>               (no description available)
un  libipc-sharedcache-p <none>               (no description available)
un  libjson-pp-perl      <none>               (no description available)
un  liblocale-codes-perl <none>               (no description available)
ii  liblocale-gettext-pe 1.05-7build1         module using libc functions for internationalization in 
un  liblocale-maketext-p <none>               (no description available)
un  liblocale-maketext-s <none>               (no description available)
un  libmarc-charset-perl <none>               (no description available)
un  libmath-bigint-perl  <none>               (no description available)
un  libmath-complex-perl <none>               (no description available)
un  libmime-base64-perl  <none>               (no description available)
un  libmodule-build-perl <none>               (no description available)
un  libmodule-corelist-p <none>               (no description available)
un  libmodule-load-condi <none>               (no description available)
un  libmodule-load-perl  <none>               (no description available)
un  libmodule-metadata-p <none>               (no description available)
un  libmodule-pluggable- <none>               (no description available)
ii  libnet-daemon-perl   0.48-1               Perl module for building portable Perl daemons easily
un  libnet-ldap-perl     <none>               (no description available)
un  libnet-perl          <none>               (no description available)
un  libnet-ping-perl     <none>               (no description available)
ii  libpango-perl        1.222-1build1        Perl module to layout and render international text
un  libparams-check-perl <none>               (no description available)
un  libparent-perl       <none>               (no description available)
un  libparse-cpan-meta-p <none>               (no description available)
un  libperl-ostype-perl  <none>               (no description available)
un  libperl4-corelibs-pe <none>               (no description available)
ii  libperl5.14          5.14.2-6ubuntu2.1    shared Perl library
un  libperl5.8           <none>               (no description available)
ii  libplrpc-perl        0.2020-2             Perl extensions for writing PlRPC servers and clients
un  libpod-escapes-perl  <none>               (no description available)
un  libpod-parser-perl   <none>               (no description available)
un  libpod-plainer-perl  <none>               (no description available)
un  libpod-simple-perl   <none>               (no description available)
un  libqtcore4-perl      <none>               (no description available)
un  libqtgui4-perl       <none>               (no description available)
un  libscalar-list-utils <none>               (no description available)
un  libshell-perl        <none>               (no description available)
un  libsql-statement-per <none>               (no description available)
un  libstorable-perl     <none>               (no description available)
ii  libswitch-perl       2.16-2               switch statement for Perl
un  libsys-syslog-perl   <none>               (no description available)
un  libterm-readkey-perl <none>               (no description available)
un  libterm-readline-gnu <none>               (no description available)
un  libterm-readline-per <none>               (no description available)
un  libtest-harness-perl <none>               (no description available)
un  libtest-simple-perl  <none>               (no description available)
ii  libtext-charwidth-pe 0.04-7build1         get display widths of characters on the terminal
ii  libtext-iconv-perl   1.7-5                converts between character sets in Perl
ii  libtext-wrapi18n-per 0.06-7               internationalized substitute of Text::Wrap
un  libthread-queue-perl <none>               (no description available)
un  libthreads-perl      <none>               (no description available)
un  libthreads-shared-pe <none>               (no description available)
un  libtime-hires-perl   <none>               (no description available)
un  libtime-local-perl   <none>               (no description available)
un  libtime-piece-perl   <none>               (no description available)
un  libunicode-collate-p <none>               (no description available)
ii  libuuid-perl         0.02-4ubuntu1        Perl extension for using UUID interfaces as defined in e
un  libversion-perl      <none>               (no description available)
un  libversion-requireme <none>               (no description available)
un  libxml-sax-perl      <none>               (no description available)
un  libxsloader-perl     <none>               (no description available)
ii  libyaml-tiny-perl    1.50-1               Perl module for reading and writing YAML files
ii  perl                 5.14.2-6ubuntu2.1    Larry Wall's Practical Extraction and Report Language
ii  perl-base            5.14.2-6ubuntu2.1    minimal Perl system
un  perl-dbdabi-94       <none>               (no description available)
un  perl-doc             <none>               (no description available)
ii  perl-modules         5.14.2-6ubuntu2.1    Core Perl modules
un  perl5                <none>               (no description available)
un  perl5-base           <none>               (no description available)
un  perlapi-5.14.2       <none>               (no description available)
un  perlsgml             <none>               (no description available)
un  podlators-perl       <none>               (no description available)
```

I completely dont know what to do...
Thank you for ahead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you need to install `libperl-dev` package.